# How to cause a seg fault on purpose

Tags: c

Allocate a dynamic variable using malloc() increment that count until a seg fault occurs. Then print out the memory addresses until the fault occurs so that the faulting address is output.

Note address should be printed before the access that causes the seg fault.

This is what I have tried so far. So far it seems it runs indefinitely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char * ptr = malloc(1);
    while(1){
        printf(" Address is %p\n", ptr++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Why would this crash? You never access the memory at the invalid pointer, you just manipulate the pointer.

Comment: Ok, you printed the pointer. You then need to dereference it (and do something with the result to stop the dereference from being optimized out).

Comment: Beware: this is a scurrilous and ill-defined exercise, and it was borderline if not actually irresponsible of your instructor to have assigned it.  I tried it on my machine, and even after adding the requisite access to `*ptr` (both read *and* write), it ran much longer than I expected, without crashing, until I killed it with control-C, lest it overwrite something important.  (No, it would be impossible for it to actually overwrite anything important, but after it ran for as long as it did, and on a fast machine incrementing `ptr` thousands of times per second, I was getting worried anyway.)

Comment: Three easier ways to cause a crash are (1) `printf("%hhx\n", *(char *)0);` (2) `*(char *)0 = 'x';` (3) `abort();`.

Comment: @SteveSummitI think the exercise is to show that usually a much larger chunk of memory is accessible than "expected".

Comment: *"the access that causes the seg fault"*, here "access" is the important word.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not an answer to the actual question, it is an answer to what others may expect to find here after reading the question from the title.

The best way of getting a program to cause a segmentation fault, is to specifically send the process itself the [`SIGSEGV`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/SIG_types) signal:

```
#include <signal.h>

int main(void) {
    raise(SIGSEGV);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following fixes your issue:

*Note that accessing unallocated memory is poor practice and this should be seen purely as an educational example, and not as good code.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *ref = malloc(1);
    unsigned char *ptr = ref;

    while (ptr++) {
        printf("%p (offset %lu)", ptr, ptr - ref);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf(": %02x\n", *ptr);
    }
}
```

I have split up the `printf` call into two parts, with a `fflush` in-between. This is to "guarantee" that the memory address (and its offset to the `malloc` call) are output, *before* it is accessed.

Otherwise, you would see the last address that *did* get accessed successfully.

The second `printf` accesses the memory and prints its byte value. This is the call that actually could cause the segmentation fault. The first one should not, because you are not accessing the actual memory, but note that you should not have arbitrary memory pointers flying around.